# differentiating between rise and raise?

Tags: vocabulary

**rise**: wages: an increase in wages(= raise American English)

**raise**: an increase in the money you earn(= rise British English)

I have extracted those from Longman.

So, are the bold terms are interchangeable in this situation?

Comment: For many speakers of AmE and BrE, they are not interchangeable. I, for example, a speaker of BrE, understand 'raise', but use only 'rise' in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

As the saying goes, when in Rome do as the Romans do. So is the case with raise and rise. When you are in the US or with the Americans, use raise and when you are in the UK or with the English, use rise and if you are in  a country where English is spoken as a second language, you can use either of the two types because the people are supposed to speak both or either of the two types of English; it is generally a hodgepodge or hotchpotch.  Don't mind; I have said it in fun. I think when it comes to an increase in a salary or wages, both nouns are interchangeable irrespective of the type you like.